# How can I migrate from "float" to "points" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, euclidean-distance

I'm looking for a faster way to calculate Euclidean distances in SQL.

- Problem I want to solve

The following "Euclidean distance calculation" is slow.

```
SELECT 
  id,
  sqrt(
    power(f1 - (-0.09077361), 2) +
    power(f2 - (0.10373443), 2) +
    ...
    ...
    power(f127 - (0.0778369), 2) +
    power(f128 - (0.00951046), 2)
  ) as distance
FROM 
  face_feature
ORDER BY 
  distance
LIMIT
  1
;
```

- What I want to know

Can you share how to migrate from "float" to "points"?

I received the following advice, but I don't understand how.

> Switch to POINTs and a SPATIAL index. It may be possible your task orders of magnitude faster.

- MySQL

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                        |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
| version                  | 8.0.29                       |
| version_comment          | MySQL Community Server - GPL |
| version_compile_machine  | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os       | Linux                        |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
```

- Table

```
mysql> desc face_feature;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| f1    | float(9,8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| f2    | float(9,8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
..
| f127  | float(9,8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| f128  | float(9,8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

- Data

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM face_feature;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   100003 |
+----------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM face_feature LIMIT 1\G;
  id: 1
  f1: -0.07603023
  f2: 0.13605964
  ...
  f127: 0.09608927
  f128: 0.00082345
```

- Reference (My other question)

[How can I make "euclidean distance calculation" faster in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72059190/how-can-i-make-euclidean-distance-calculation-faster-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `FLOAT(M,N)` it adds an extra rounding that only hurts various operations.
- `FLOAT(9,8)`, if the numbers are near "1.0" will lose some precision.  This is because there are only 24 bits of precision in any `FLOAT`.
- `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` has been deprecated (as useless and misleading) in newer versions of MySQL.
- There are helper functions to convert numeric strings to `POINT` values.  Internally, a `POINT` contains two `DOUBLEs`.  Hence the original `DECIMAL(9,8)` loses only a round-from-decimal-to-binary at the 53rd significant bit.

But the real question is about using `SPATIAL` indexing when the universe has 128 dimensions.  I don't think it will work.  (I have not even heard of using `SPATIAL` for 3 dimensions, though it should be practical.)